# Exporting gridview with paging

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

so I'm trying to export a Gridview into Excel but keep getting this result whenever I download the gridview. If I comment out the allowpaging & databind then it works however I need to keep it in order to download a gridview with paging. Any ideas on what to do? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIMfh.jpg

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
    }

    protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Destinations.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

        StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);


        DestinationGridView.AllowPaging = false;
        DestinationGridView.DataBind();

        this.DestinationGridView.Columns[10].Visible = false;
        this.DestinationGridView.Columns[13].Visible = false;


        DestinationGridView.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }

 <div style="overflow-x: scroll; width: 100%">
                <asp:GridView ID="DestinationGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10" OnSorting="DestinationGridView_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="DestinationGridView_PageIndexChanging" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="DestName" SortExpression="DestName" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pick up or Delivery" DataField="isPickup" SortExpression="isPickup" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address 1" DataField="Address1" SortExpression="Address1" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address 2" DataField="Address2" SortExpression="Address2" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City" DataField="City" SortExpression="City" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="State" DataField="State" SortExpression="State" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Zip" DataField="ZipCode" SortExpression="ZipCode" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Region" DataField="RegionName" SortExpression="RegionName" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Priority" DataField="DestinationPriority" SortExpression="DestinationPriority" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recurring" DataField="isScheduled" SortExpression="isScheduled" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Recurring">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewRecurring" runat="server" class="btn btn-default btn-info" OnClick="btnViewRecurring_Click" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View Recurring Information">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Active" DataField="isActive" SortExpression="isActive" />

                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Notes" DataField="DesNotes" SortExpression="DesNotes" />

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditModal" class="btn btn-default btn-success" OnClick="btnEditModal_Click" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Destination">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension. And export the source data, not the gridview itself.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into it.